# Unprotected page appears protected when posted to Facebook (S2Member)

Tags: facebook, s2member

I recently removed the restriction on the following page:

http://www.boulderwritersworkshop.org/2012/10/21/david-jessup/

I can now view it without being logged in. However, if I post this URL to my Facebook wall, it shows the "Join" page, as if Facebook thinks I need to log in the view that content. I tried clearing Quick Cache and loading the page from a remote computer--it's definitely visible to all. Except Facebook apparently.

Ideas?

Comment: I'd post to s2Member's forum about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the trailing slash and it works fine.

```
http://www.boulderwritersworkshop.org/2012/10/21/david-jessup
```